# How to get the correct date from this grouped data?

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by

I have a dataset with data which has a value every 5 mins.  Now I have this group by LINQ query where I group this data in hourly slots.

I want to get the correct `Timestamp` for each hour, I used `n.First().Timestamp` here, but from my results it seems wrong.  On a dataset with a few years data, I only get 24 points back.

`Node` looks like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public double Value;
    public string NodeName;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I can get the right `Timestamp` of the hourly grouped data?  So instead of having a `Timestamp` like `1/01/2014 14:05:00`, `1/01/2014 14:10:00`, I'd just have for every hourly grouping `1/01/2014 14:00:00`, `1/01/2014 15:00:00`.

```
hourlynodes = (from node in nodedata group node by node.Timestamp.Hour into n select new Node 
{ Timestamp = new DateTime(n.First().Timestamp.Year, // How do I get the right Year/Month/Day for each grouped hour???
  n.First().Timestamp.Month, 
  n.First().Timestamp.Day, 
  n.Key, 0, 0),  // n.Key here is the hour grouping
  Value = n.Average(x => x.Value), 
  NodeName = n.First().NodeName 
}
).OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp.Date);
```

Comment: How your Node class looks like? And what getting timestamp back to hour means?

Comment: The reason you're getting 24 points back is because you're grouping by just the hour, without including the day, month, year...

Comment: Please provide some sample data table and results you want to get. It's not clear whether date and node name matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **SELECT** to the nearest hour, not just use that hour as the basis. So you'll need an extension method:

```
public static DateTime ToNearestHour(this DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.Date.AddHours(dt.Hours);
}
```

Then it's as simple as slightly modifying the group.

```
hourlynodes = (from node in nodedata group node by node.Timestamp.ToNearestHour() into n select new Node 
{ Timestamp = new DateTime(n.First().Timestamp.Year, // How do I get the right Year/Month/Day for each grouped hour???
  n.First().Timestamp.Month, 
  n.First().Timestamp.Day, 
  n.Key, 0, 0),  // n.Key here is the hour grouping
  Value = n.Average(x => x.Value), 
  NodeName = n.First().NodeName 
}
).OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp.Date);
```